# Haskell 2^n functional programming

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I am trying to do **Haskell** version of **2^n integer list**. numsFrom generate infinite sequence, I want to map this sequence into number 2, but I have an error message:

> Possible cause: ‘map’ is applied to too many arguments.

```
numsFrom :: Int -> [Int]
numsFrom n = n : numsFrom (n+1)

powerOf2 :: Int -> [Int]
powerOf2 = map(^numsFrom 1) 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`powerOf2` signature must be `powerOf2 :: [Int]`. `numsFrom` returns a list to be mapped, so the function to map is `(2^)`:

```
powerOf2 :: [Int]
powerOf2 = map (2^) (numsFrom 1)
```

PD: Note that you don't need `numsFrom` function:

```
powerOf2 :: [Int]
powerOf2 = map (2^) [1..]
```

Comment: Note that `map (2^) [1..] == [2,4,8,16,...]` and `iterate (*2) 1 == [1,2,4,8,16,...]` are slightly different. The `map` version can include `2^0` by mapping over `[0..]` instead; the iterate version can exclude it by starting with 2 instead of 1.